# drilling down in PHP using hyperlinks

Tags: php

I am a novice at PHP and i have encountered a problem with the following code...

```
<?php 
 // Connects to Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT country_id, country_name FROM country, channels WHERE channels.channel_id = country.channel_id AND channels.channel_id = '1'") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
  echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=15>";
echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white>
<td><b>Country ID</b></td><td><b>Country Name</b></td>" ; 
 while (mysql_fetch_row($data)) {
$cid = mysql_result($data, 1);
$cname = mysql_result($data, 2);

# inserts value into table as a hyperlink

echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white><td>$cid</td><td><a href=view_country_detail.php?cid=$cid>$cname</td>";
}

# displays table

print '</table>';

 ?>
```

to explain the problem i am getting, i am after generated hyperlinks to drill down to the companies which share the to be clicked country's id from the code above to then display a similar layout on the 'view_country_detail' page. i cant work out why the output for the table gives me a repeated row for the first two id's for the country column in the db. any help would be greatly appreciated as i am totally lost here. Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the SQL code directly in the database? Does that have the repeated rows too?

Comment: no, thats what i am struggling with. if i take out the hyperlink feature it displays what i want the country_id | country_name

Comment: and i want that each specific country name to drill-down in the form of a hyperink to show the counties belonging to the clicked country

Comment: By the way you're not closing your a-tag proberly.

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but since you're a novice: don't bother with `mysql_*`, it has begun its deprecation process, and is highly discouraged, use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try structuring your `while` loop as follows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
      $cid = $row[0];  //if you have the column names, replace 0 with 'column_name'
      $cname = $row[1];

      //then echo statement
 }
```

Also, `mysql_*` functions have started the deprecation process and should no longer be used, even the php manual pages state the use of `mysql_*` is discouraged.  Look into using the similar [mysqli_* functions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or PDO.

Comment: that has sorted it, thanks. another brief query, how then would i post the $cid to the next page (view_county_detil) for example to then drill down another level?

Comment: If you're looking to carry variables from one page to the next, you have several options. Either store it in a session variable, store it in a GET var, or put it in a hidden input field of a POST form and send that form to the next page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you use `mysql_fetch_row` and then don't want to actually use the row you fetch.

You should not be using `mysql_result` here. What you are doing is fetching data from row 1 of the result set and then data from row 2 regardless of which row the pointer is on in your while loop.

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $cid = $row['country_id'];
    $cname = $row['country_name'];
}
```

I personally find it much more readable in code to reference the fields by the associative keys used when using `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_array`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($data)) {
    $cid = $row[0];
    $cname = $row[1];
    ...
}
```

`mysql_fetch_row` returns an array.

**HOWEVER**

You should look at stopping using the mysql_* functions - they're being deprecated. If you switch to PDO or mysqli, it helps make your code more secure, too.